# Does dropout improve models even with access to infinite data?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, reinforcement-learning

Are there well understood guidelines of when to use dropout versus simply get more data? I had previously understood that, given sufficient data, one wouldn't want to use dropout. However, I recently had a model (4 layer LSTM processing audio input) that empirically converged to a certain loss no matter how much data I provided - and was then improved significantly when I added dropout.

Is this phenomena well understood? Should one always use dropout then, even when there is more (potentially infinite) data available?

Follow-up: if so, I haven't seen much mention of dropout in RL papers. I'd assumed this is because there is infinite generable data. Are there other nuances to consider here about the fraction of the state space explored, or the heterogeneity of the training data available etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropout reduces your train accuracy in exchange for test accuracy. However your performance on the data is bounded by the training accuracy. In a world with infinite independent distributed data it would be possible to obtain performance on the problem equal to the training set, because in essence its the same data.

However in practice you will never have such a good training set. Even if you obtain infinite data it will not represent your distribution and will definitely not be independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Thomas. Very concise description of tradeoff. It sounds like you're saying there are *not* benefits to using dropout with an unbounded and perfect training set, but given the likelihood of dependence in the training set it might still be useful - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise prescription for dropout - as [Hinton's group 2014 paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) seems to confirm.  However they write there that:

> Dropout introduces a significant amount of noise in the gradients
>   compared to standard stochastic gradient descent. Therefore, a lot of
>   gradients tend to cancel each other. In order to make up for this, a
>   dropout net should typically use 10-100 times the learning rate that
>   was optimal for a standard neural net.

So my naive guess is a factor of 10-100 of additional training data is necessary.  Note also the using dropout can practically triple the number of training regimes needed - an additional factor to bear in mind.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Gavin. You're saying naively you'd need 10-100x the data to equal the regularization obtained with dropout? Or that dropout means you'd need more data? Former makes sense to me, though I'm specifically curious if there are reasons dropout is useful even beyond preventing overfitting (e.g. enforcement of compact representations, robustness to noise, etc)